# (C#) How to remove the "Hello World" line when starting a new console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I am using Visual Studio 2017. When I start a new Console App(.NET Core) it comes with a Console.WriteLine("Hello World!") by default. My question is if there is a way to permanently remove this line instead of deleting it every single time?

Comment: create a project template? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates - but frankly: it would be easier to just *delete the line*

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own project template. Get your project set up how you like, then in VS, go to the Project menu and select "Export Project". Follow the prompts from there. Then, next time you create a new project, you will be able to find your exported template in the project type selector.

Or delete the line.